# ARM and Intel assembly instruction mapping

Tags: assembly, arm, intel

This might be a silly question, but is there a webpage/document/book that gives you a mapping of intel x86 and ARM assembly instructions?

I'm aware that it's not a 1-to-1 mapping, but I would assume that many instructions do map over rather seamlessly (MOV, as an example).

Comment: `MOV` in particular is anything but a seamless mapping. For one, _immediate_ `MOV` (initializing a register with a constant) on ARM is a _synthetic_ instruction (the assembler may reconstitute it from two real instructions). Second, ARM `MOV` can _extract_ parts of a register thanks to the barrel shifter - to do that on x86, an `SHL`/`SHR` pair are required, or at best a zero-extending `MOVZ`; ARM is far more flexible there. Third, moving to/from memory on ARM is done by `STR`/`LDR` instruction, not `MOV`. There might be other differences ... that's just what immediately comes to mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why? Are you trying to port code from one to the other? Do you know one and want a "cheat sheet" to learn the other? The best I can come up with is an [ARM/Thumb Quick Reference Card](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.qrc0001l/QRC0001_UAL.pdf) (there are probably *many* for x86).

I can't seem to find one, and perhaps the main reason that the mapping is far from "seamless". ARM instructions are generally 3-op  (`abc dst,src1,src2`), and to make matters worse, `src2` can have shifts/rotates applied to it. x86 instructions are generally 2-op, except you have oddities like `lea` which is commonly used as a 3-op add.

The closest thing I can think of is a combined ARM/x86 cheat sheet, with common instructions separated into categories (arithmetic, bit ops, control flow, floating point, memory access).

And then there's Thumb...

Comment: This is just general curiosity.

Answer (score 1):

instruction set architectures have and use similar sounding and functioning instructions, like add, xor, load, store, and move.

The mapping you are looking for is found in the same place no matter what the two instruction sets are.  Get the docs for one instruction set, get the docs for another and just look up the instructions.  x86 likes to overload the mov instruction for loads and stores as well as move immediate and register to register moves, for arm you use load and store for load and store and move for register to register and immediate to register.

intel is cisc, arm is risc, so there is not going to be a one to one map.  very few instructions will map seemlessly, add rd=rd+rn and other register to register alu functions (for full sized registers not the fractional x86 registers).

As a result of not being seemless and not a one to one map, there are multiple valid solutions for going from one to the other so finding a single map doesnt make sense.

What you are looking for is either a static binary translation or a dynamic binary translation, static is easier if you have never done one.  And dont translate from one machine code to another assembly or machine code.  Translate from machine code to C then let a compiler compile that down to the target while optimizing and also giving you a choice to use different targets.  An other alternative is an instruction set simulator.

If you are looking to just re-write some code by hand, use the two instruction set manuals source and target.  even if there were a map, you would still need to have a good knowledge of the two instruction sets to use that map.